# How to restore iPhone backups without a SIM?

Tags: iphone, itunes, sim

I have an iPhone 5 with a damaged SIM slot.  How does one restore an iPhone using file backups made from iPhone 5 without having to insert a sim card or using Xcode?  Using the MDBACKUP files or restore from a IPSW file?

Is there a way to convert the last phone MDBACKUP files into an .ipsw and then load this file in iTunes via recovery mode to restore it?

I learned a valuable lesson and that was never use a cable that is not OEM when trying to upgrade. About 6 months ago I was upgrading the iPhone 5 (Sprint) via iTunes. The upgrade failed due to the cable. Now every boot iPhone 5 says insert sim card. (The Hello Screen)
  
I did make complete backups on computer before the upgrade.
The worst part is that the sim port has damaged pins inside and there is no way even when I'm just using the iPhone on Wi-Fi to have a sim card to be recognized.

I even went as far as adding the IMEI to a developer account for testing and tried that way. Any way using Xcode to figure a way this way or loading the backup files.  IMEI is clean and I was just using this iPhone on WiFi only for a year.

Anyone know if it is possible to restore using the file backups somehow? Is there no way without having to insert a sim? Any way to get to the Apple login screen?

Comment: IPSW files are signed, so you can't convert into them. I'm confused why it is you can't just go into DFU and restore normally